# How add tags to new node in Drupal 7 using php script?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, tags, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to add new articles in Drupal 7 from php script. How to add new tags to Drupal and than add this new tags to created node?

In wordpress thing is easy, all we need is using buildin function:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append )
```

Is there a similar function in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

In the Drupal world, you can take advantage of the  node_save() fuction. Working example here https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922.
Thanks for your feedback